# Bing API Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, api, search, bing

This has been asked before but no solution given.

I have created an account with https://datamarket.azure.com/account/keys and I have a primary account key and a customer id.

I got the code below from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd440739.aspx
I have tried replacing `<yourAppIdHere>` with the values of both the primary account key and the customer id, but in each case get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

What am I missing here? Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
   <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <title>PHP Bing</title>
</head>
<body><form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"> 
 Type in a search:<input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" value="<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['searchText'])){
  echo($_POST['searchText']); }
  else { echo('sushi');}
  ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search!" name="submit" id="searchButton" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$request = 'http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?Appid=<YourAppIDHere>&sources=image&query=' . urlencode( $_POST["searchText"]);
$response  = file_get_contents($request);
$jsonobj  = json_decode($response);
echo('<ul ID="resultList">');                    

foreach($jsonobj->SearchResponse->Image->Results as $value)
{
echo('<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="' . $value->Url . '">');
echo('<img src="' . $value->Thumbnail->Url. '"></li>');

}
echo("</ul>");
} ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the dump of `$jsonobj`?

Comment: `object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["SearchResponse"]=> object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["Version"]=> string(3) "2.2" ["Query"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["SearchTerms"]=> string(5) "sushi" } ["Errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (5) { ["Code"]=> int(1002) ["Message"]=> string(28) "Parameter has invalid value." ["Parameter"]=> string(19) "SearchRequest.AppId" ["Value"]=> string(43) "*************************************" ["HelpUrl"]=> string(53) "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251042.aspx" } } } }` 
Looks like the AppId is invalid. How is this differnt from the account key?

Comment: It says in the message `Parameter has invalid value.` That's why you're getting the invalid foreach since the response has no `Image->Results`

Comment: Yes. I get that. My issue is: why is it invalid? I've tried a valid account key and customer id. Looks like I'm missing some vital piece of understanding. I even tried creating an app, and putting the app name in there, but no luck.

Comment: What is the dump of your `$_POST["searchText"]`?

Comment: string(3) "whatever I entered in form"

Comment: Are you sure the Parameter is `SearchRequest.AppId`? Since it says it has an invalid value.